# The growing popularity of “on the cusp”

Tags: idioms, phrase-usage

The term ***[cusp](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cusp)***  is an old one and it was first used in astrology and later in other contexts:

> ***1580s, in astrology***, "first entrance of a house in the calculation of a nativity," from Latin cuspis "point, spear, pointed end, head," which is of unknown origin. ***Astronomical sense is from 1670s,***  "point or horn of a crescent." ***Anatomical sense*** of "a prominence on the crown of a tooth" is from 1839. (Etymonline)

but the metaphorical expression ***[on the cusp of something](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20the%20cusp)*** meaning “*be at the time when a situation or state is going to change*” became curiously popular only a few decades ago, from the 1990s as shown by ***[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20the%20cusp&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20cusp%3B%2Cc0).***

[image]

While it probably derives  from the astrological use of cusp, I wonder what may have caused its popularity  which, as shown, has been  increasing  steadily and consistently in recent years.

Comment: I never knew there was such a thing as "the astrological use of cusp", but I seriously doubt it's particularly significant in relation to ***on the cusp of** [some significant change]*. Not quite so marked, but there's been a significant increase in prevalence of [*on the **verge** of*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+verge+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20verge%20of%3B%2Cc0) in recent decades, too. Some usages go in and out of fashion, is all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Born on the Leo/Virgo cusp etc. Either on the last day or on the first day of an astrological sign, supposedly, the lucky earthling shares characterial traits of both signs..

Comment: Maybe it's partly just that across the whole of the Anglophone world, more people are being exposed to more different "turns of phrase" than was the case many decades ago. And *some* of the previously-unfamiliar expressions they encounter are so striking they get repeated more...

Comment: ...Witness the same thing happening with, for example, [***rife / ripe with opportunity***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rife+with+opportunity%2Cripe+with+opportunity&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crife%20with%20opportunity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cripe%20with%20opportunity%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crife%20with%20opportunity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cripe%20with%20opportunity%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I would be saddened to think that more people are interested in astrology today than 50 years ago! :(

Comment: @FumbleFingers mediums, psychics, magicians and illusionists are just as popular today as ever. But I think the OP's question is about why the vertiginous rise. It's not due to the obvious decline of horoscope magazines and newspaper articles, which were hugely popular back in the 70s and 80s, so what is "on the cusp"?

Comment: I think it has to do with being on the cusp of a new millenium, a new century, and being on the cusp of extinction, global warming etc. Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

[This ngram compares](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20the%20cusp%2Con%20the%20way%2Con%20the%20verge%2CY2K%2Cend%20of%20the%20world%2Con%20the%20edge%20of%2Cglobal%20warming&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Con%20the%20cusp%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20cusp%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20cusp%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20Cusp%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20Cusp%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Con%20the%20way%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20way%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20way%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20Way%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Con%20the%20verge%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20verge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20verge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CY2K%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BY2K%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BY2k%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cend%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bend%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEnd%20of%20the%20World%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bend%20of%20the%20World%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEND%20OF%20THE%20WORLD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Con%20the%20edge%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20edge%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20edge%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cglobal%20warming%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bglobal%20warming%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGlobal%20Warming%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGlobal%20warming%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGLOBAL%20WARMING%3B%2Cc0) some apparently  unrelated data. The timeline starts at 1960, and ends 2019. It seems to show an increase in many expressions relating to  "on the cusp" starting roughly 1995, correspondingly  with "Y2K";  and then increasing  incrementally with my baseline ("on the way") , even though"Y2K" usage dropped  significantly after 2001.

[image]

*[ngrams started 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Ngram_Viewer), and only collects data until 2019. Perhaps it is due to  a data collection bias.

Also interesting is that "Global Warming" dropped in mention by a significant percentage, even though "end of the world" crept up in usage, and  *Extinction Level Event* never came close in any search...

I think "on the cusp" is just another  expression that describes a certain type of morbid foreboding of a future change.

[I have seen past data that suggests that the majority of US citizens in the late 1930s  *knew* there would be another great war in their then  near future. But that would be out-of-scope for the question.]

My analysis:

***This data indicates a fear of the future, and   a reluctance to investigate the science.***

Comment: The decrease in "global warming" coincides with a big increase in "climate change". [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=climate+change%2Cglobal+warming&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cclimate%20change%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bclimate%20change%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BClimate%20Change%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BClimate%20change%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCLIMATE%20CHANGE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cglobal%20warming%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bglobal%20warming%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGlobal%20Warming%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGlobal%20warming%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGLOBAL%20WARMING%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I don't associate "on the cusp" specifically with changes for the worse or foreboding.